# how to create, print and use variables using a loop in Mathematica?

Tags: output-formatting, symbolic

I want to create, print and be able to use (i.e. do symbolic operations) variables in *Mathematica* using a for loop or equivalent.

So, I have a bunch of variables of this form:

$$dS_i = -\beta_i S_i$$
where $i$ is an index.

I would like to end up with the variables defined in the notebook like this:

$$dS_1 = -\beta_1 S_1$$
$$dS_2 = -\beta_2 S_2$$
$$dS_3 = -\beta_3 S_3$$

etc.

So that I can see each of them in my screen *and* I can actually perform symbolic operations with them (e.g. $dS_1 + dS_2$).

If I do:

```
Do[Print["dI", i, "= -beta", i, "*S"], {i, 4}]
```

then I get the printing part but they are not variables, just strings.

I have also tried:

```
Table[dI[i] = -beta[i]*S, {i, 4}]
```

which generates the variables but then I don't get to see them on the screen.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider using `[[]]` a.k.a `Part` instead of `[]`. And also this question just needs more details. You can always use the symbolic entities and pipe them to, say, `Grid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
expr[i_] := Defer[dS[i] = -β[i]*S]

Do[expr[i][[1]]; CellPrint@Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@expr[i], "Output"], {i, 4}]
```

In the `Do` loop I evaluate the assignment and also create a cell with the definition. You could use "Input" instead of "Output" if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Simon, with the Input option this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like the following:

```
Table[dS[i] = -β[i]*S[i], {i, 4}];
```

To see the definitions for `dS` use the function [`Definition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html).

```
Definition[dS]
(* 
dS[1]=-S[1] β[1]

dS[2]=-S[2] β[2]

dS[3]=-S[3] β[3]

dS[4]=-S[4] β[4] 
*)
```

See that you can perform operations on `dS`.

```
dS[1] + dS[2]
(* -S[1] β[1] - S[2] β[2] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dos this work

```
Do[dI[i] = -beta[i]*S; Print["dI", i, "= -beta", i, "*S"], {i, 4}]
```

Any method that can print what you want has to change the expression to a kid of String. At the end, the printed expression the way you what has to be kind of String

You can try `Inactivate`

```
Do[dI[i] = -beta[i]*S; Print[Inactivate[dI[i] = -beta[i]*S]], {i, 4}]
```

Comment: Thanks Algohi, it kind of works, not exactly what I wanted...
 If I change what you wrote a bit, like this:

        Do[dI[i] = -beta[i]*S; Print["dI[", i, "]= -beta", i, "*S"], {i, 4}]

the variables in memory match the ones being printed on the screen, but what is printed is still strings, if you understand what I mean...